# Angular Metadata version mismatch

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-module

I´m using angular 4 and angular cli in my project, i just install the `ng2-img-max` to manipulate images before upload to my firebase storage, but when i run the `ng server` i get this error: `Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/Migue/Desktop/weddingAngular/node_modules/ng2-img-max/dist/ng2-img-max.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/Migue/Desktop/weddingAngular/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/Migue/Desktop/weddingAngular/src/app/app.module.ts`

this is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "wedding-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.14.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "ng2-animate-on-scroll": "^1.0.6",
    "ng2-img-max": "^2.1.9",
    "ng2-scroll-to": "^1.0.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

any idea what could be problem.

Comment: Try to downgrade the version number of ng2-img-max to 2.1.0 and run npm install again.

Comment: Yeap that make the trick, thanks so much for your help, could you please post it as an answer to check as solved. @GregorDoroschenko

Comment: Answer is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade the version of `ng2-img-max` to `2.1.0` because the developer updates dependencies in `2.1.4` for supporting angular 5.

For more information see the commits of `2.1.4`:
https://github.com/bergben/ng2-img-max/compare/2.1.4...master

You see that devDependencies of `2.1.4` require angular 5:

```
"devDependencies": {
-        "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
-        "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
-        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.8",
-        "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
-        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
-        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
-        "@angular/router": "3.4.8",
-        "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
+        "@angular/common": ">=5.0.0",
+        "@angular/compiler": ">=5.0.0",
+        "@angular/compiler-cli": ">=5.0.0",
+        "@angular/core": ">=5.0.0",
+        "@angular/platform-browser": ">=5.0.0",
+        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ">=5.0.0",
+        "@angular/router": ">=5.0.0",
+        "@types/node": ">=7.0.5",
         "core-js": "^2.4.1",
         "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
         "rollup": "^0.41.4",
         "rxjs": "5.1.1",
         "tslint": "^4.4.2",
-        "typescript": "^2.1.6",
+        "typescript": "~2.4.2",
         "uglify-js": "^2.7.5",
         "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
     },
```