# angular : ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module

Tags: angular

hy , I have an error when I compile angular 4 with ng serve:

ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /node_modules/ng2-img-max/dist/ng2-img-max.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol DirectiveModule in /src/app/directives/directive.module.ts, resolving symbol DirectiveModule in /src/app/directives/directive.module.ts

my  package.json :

```
{
  "name": "ldp-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-tinymce": "^2.1.2",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.14.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^3.0.3",
    "ng2-img-max": "2.1.6",
    "ng2-materialize": "^1.7.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Downgrade the version of ng2-img-max to 2.1.0 for more reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812451/angular-metadata-version-mismatch

Answer (score 3):

go to node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

and open file angular-2-dropdown-multiselect.metadata.json and change version 4 to 3